# Does ember-cli support object literal shorthands?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ecmascript-6

**UPDATE 2**

I've filed an issue at the ember-cli repo describing simple steps to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/4015.

---

**UPDATE**

This is related to using in-repo-addons. The ember compiler does not choke when using this syntax in your regular app. I will be filing a bug report at http://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli shortly with steps to reproduce and will link back to the issue here when it is ready.

---

I caught the bug for es6 and started using the object literal method shorthand:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    didInsertElement() {
        // stuff I want to do once we're in the DOM
    }
})
```

but it chokes when running `ember build --environment production`. Thoughts?

```
Build failed.
Unexpected token punc «(», expected punc «:»
```

Comment: Can you post a gist of your package.json to see what versions of dependencies there are? Also try naming the function something different from didInsertElement and then add the event like this: somethingOnDidInsertElement(){ }.on('didInsertElement');

Comment: huh. testing on a blank install. it might be related to the code being in an in-repo-addon. standbye

Comment: What version of npm/node are you using?

Comment: Also could you could give a gist of your brocfile?

Comment: Try calling this._super() inside the didInsertElement()

Comment: @MichaelBenin, npm is 2.7.6, node is 0.12.0. The brocfile is the default generated by ember-cli and it's not a run-time error, it's a compile-time error, adding `this._super()` won't make a difference. See my second update for steps to reproduce on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Repo Addons (currently) require `ember-cli-babel` as a dependency.

```
$ cd lib/<your addon>
$ npm install ember-cli-babel --save
$ cd ../..
$ ember build --environment production
```

Answer (score 0):

Ember-cli uses babel which does support object literal shorthands.

See:

https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es6/

Comment: yes but there have been other documented bugs when using an in-repo-addon. See my updated above and stay tuned for a bug report with reproducable stpe.s